# Select the first word from a column that may have more words

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a `table` simple as this:

```
id    |    name
1     |    one_word
2     |    two words
3     |    here we have four
```

So, I would like to get only rows containing one word, which in the above example would only be record with id `2`.

I did [read the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html) and tried various versions of this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name REGEXP '(.*?)\s';
```

so, please tell me where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Rows 2 and 3 have spaces in them

Comment: id 2 contains two words... you need id 1?

Comment: ah, damn, you're right!! I just select those who haven't got spaces, doh! Thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the first word from a column that may have more words, you can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("here we have four", " ", 1)
```

to extract rows that don't have spaces, you can use for example this:

- `name NOT REGEXP '\s'`
- `name NOT LIKE '% %'`
- `LOCATE(' ', name) = 0`

if your column can contain spaces at the beginning or at the end of the string, you could also use [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM("  here we have four  "), " ", 1)
```

- `TRIM(name) NOT REGEXP '\s'`
- `TRIM(name) NOT LIKE '% %'`
- `LOCATE(' ', TRIM(name)) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Thx to the comment from Strawberry, I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name NOT REGEXP '\s'
```

which works great.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? In both `LIKE '% %'` and `REGEXP` case performance is bad. But i think `LIKE` has the least bad performance.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name NOT LIKE '% %'
```